# JQuery game only plays through one round, won't restart

Tags: jquery

I have a pretty simple random number adding game where you click on images to try to add up to a target number.

It plays through one round, you win or lose, it resets the target score and the randomly selected images, but the image clicks don't function in the second round.

I've tried to doing my initialize and reset functions in multiple ways, but nothing I can think of (which is not very much, I'm very new to coding) seems to work.

Here's the script:

```
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;
var counter = 0;
var randomNumberToGuess = [];

function reset(){
    $("#crystal").empty();
    $("#score").empty();
    counter = 0;
    randomNumberToGuess = [];
    initialize();
}

function initialize(){

randomNumberToGuess = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + 19];

$("#number-to-guess").text(randomNumberToGuess);
```

//loops through all numberOptions, makes a crystal and a value for each...

```
var numberOptions = ["crystal1", "crystal2", "crystal3", "crystal4"];

for (var i = 0; i < numberOptions.length; i++) {

    var images = ["assets/images/mind.png", "assets/images/power.png", 
"assets/images/reality.png", "assets/images/soul.png", 
"assets/images/space.png", "assets/images/time.png"];

    var imageCrystal = $("<img>");

    imageCrystal.addClass("crystal");



    imageCrystal.attr("src", images[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
images.length)]);


//this gives the crystals a randomly assigned value
    imageCrystal.attr("data-crystalvalue", [Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 
1]);




imageCrystal.attr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1];


$("#crystal").append(imageCrystal);

}
}

initialize();

$(".crystal").on("click", function() {


var crystalValue = ($(this).attr("data-crystalvalue"));

crystalValue = parseInt(crystalValue);


counter += crystalValue;

$("#score").text(counter);

if (counter == randomNumberToGuess){
    alert("You win!");
    wins++;
    $("#wins").text(wins);
    reset();

}

else if (counter > randomNumberToGuess) {
    alert("You lose!");
    losses++;
    $("#losses").text(losses);
    reset();


}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate you click events, your images are dynamically added

```
$('body').on("click",".crystal", function() {
......
```